# Multiple opacities and widths in Mapbox - Plotly for Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, mapbox

**This is a question that derives from a previous one, which can be found here**: [Multiple opacities in Mapbox - Plotly for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351757/multiple-opacities-in-mapbox-plotly-for-python/70361110?noredirect=1#comment124735963_70361110)

I was having some issues regarding having multiple opacities for multiple traces on a Mapbox map, each opacity associated with a particular value of the dataframe.

After following Rob's helpful answer (see link above), which led to the solution on the first topic, I found myself in another problem, as I want now kind of twist on his code.

While my first approach was to only have variations on the opacity of the traces, I would now need to have **both** variations on the opacity **and** the width of each trace, corresponding each of them to a different value on a particular dataframe.

I proceed to copy-paste the first part of Rob's answer, where he declares some functions and creates a dataframe:

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

# get geometry of london underground stations
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    requests.get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oobrien/vis/master/tube/data/tfl_stations.json"
    ).json()
)

# limit to zone 1 and stations that have larger number of lines going through them
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf["zone"].isin(["1","2","3","4","5","6"]) & gdf["lines"].apply(len).gt(0)].reset_index(
    drop=True
).rename(columns={"id":"tfl_id", "name":"id"})

# wanna join all valid combinations of stations...
combis = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(gdf.index, 2)))

# generate dataframe of all combinations of stations
gdf_c = (
    gdf.loc[combis[:, 0], ["geometry", "id"]]
    .assign(right=combis[:, 1])
    .merge(gdf.loc[:, ["geometry", "id"]], left_on="right", right_index=True, suffixes=("_start_station","_end_station"))
)


gdf_c["lat_start_station"] = gdf_c["geometry_start_station"].apply(lambda g: g.y)
gdf_c["long_start_station"] = gdf_c["geometry_start_station"].apply(lambda g: g.x)
gdf_c["lat_end_station"] = gdf_c["geometry_end_station"].apply(lambda g: g.y)
gdf_c["long_end_station"] = gdf_c["geometry_end_station"].apply(lambda g: g.x)

gdf_c = gdf_c.drop(
    columns=[
        "geometry_start_station",
        "right",
        "geometry_end_station",
    ]
).assign(number_of_journeys=np.random.randint(1,10**5,len(gdf_c)))

gdf_c
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO.csv")
gdf_c.to_csv(f, index=False)

# there's an requirement to start with a CSV even though no sample data has been provided, now we're starting with a CSV
df = pd.read_csv(f)

# makes use of ravel simpler...
df["none"] = None
```

My particular problem starts here: when trying to create two "loops" (one for opacity, and one for width), I thought I could do the following:

```
BINS_FOR_OPACITY=10
opacity_a = np.geomspace(0.001,1, BINS_FOR_OPACITY)
BINS_FOR_WIDTH=10
width_a = np.geomspace(1,3, BINS_FOR_WIDTH)

fig = go.Figure()

# Note the double "for" statement that follows

for opacity, d in df.groupby(pd.cut(df["number_of_journeys"], bins=BINS_FOR_OPACITY, labels=opacity_a)):
    for width, d in df.groupby(pd.cut(df["number_of_journeys"], bins=BINS_FOR_WIDTH, labels=width_a)):
        fig.add_traces(
            go.Scattermapbox(
                name=f"{d['number_of_journeys'].mean():.2E}",
                lat=np.ravel(d.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if "lat" in c or c=="none"]].values),
                lon=np.ravel(d.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if "long" in c or c=="none"]].values),
                line_width=width
                line_color="blue",
                opacity=opacity,
                mode="lines+markers",
        )
    )
```

[Rob's original answer had only the first `for` statement, and not the second one]

However, the above is clearly not working, as it is making much more traces than it should do (I really can't explain why, but I guess it might be because of the double loop forced by the two `for` statements).

It ocurred to me that some kind of solution could be hidding in the `pd.cut` part, as I would need *something like* a double cut, but couldn't find a way to properly doing it.

I also managed to create a Pandas series by:

```
widths = pd.cut(df.["size"], bins=BINS_FOR_WIDTH, labels=width_a)
```

and iterating over that series, but got the same result as before (an excess of traces).

To emphasize and clarify myself, I don't need to have **only** multiple opacities or multiple widths, but I need to have them **both** and **at the same time**, which is what's causing me some troubles.

I am deeply grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- given you are using same column to define *width* and *opacity* you only need one loop
- for *width* I think linear space is better than geometric space,  hence have created `width_a` as below
- both `opacity` and `width` will move in step as it's cutting same column by same number of bins

### solution excluding data sourcing

```
BINS = 10
opacity_a = np.geomspace(0.001, 1, BINS)
width_a = np.linspace(0.1, 2, BINS)
fig = go.Figure()
for (opacity, width), d in df.groupby(
    [
        pd.cut(df["number_of_journeys"], bins=BINS, labels=opacity_a),
        pd.cut(df["number_of_journeys"], bins=BINS, labels=width_a),
    ]
):
    fig.add_traces(
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name=f"{d['number_of_journeys'].mean():.2E}",
            lat=np.ravel(
                d.loc[:, [c for c in df.columns if "lat" in c or c == "none"]].values
            ),
            lon=np.ravel(
                d.loc[:, [c for c in df.columns if "long" in c or c == "none"]].values
            ),
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=width,
            opacity=opacity,
            mode="lines+markers",
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {"lat": 51.520214996769255, "lon": -0.097792388774743},
        "zoom": 9,
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

Comment: Whoa! Didn't know it was possible to pass two `pd.cut` arguments into the `df.groupby`. It worked wonderfully. Thank you for all your help!